# How to retrieve compound fields like address using Bulk API?

Tags: bulk-api

Attempting to retrieve address fields (such as `BillingAddress` on `Account`) via Bulk API gives an error:

> Failed to process query: FUNCTIONALITY_NOT_ENABLED: Selecting compound
>   data not supported in Bulk Query

Sure enough, [the Bulk API docs say](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_using_bulk_query.htm):

> Bulk API can’t access or query compound address or compound geolocation fields.

Is there really no way to access address and geolocation data via the Bulk API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a clue in this [help page on compound fields](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000204592):

> Compound fields can't be included in Bulk queries. Use the individual field components to access or update field values.

It turns out that you can use the component fields like so:

```
SELECT BillingStreet, BillingCity, 
       BillingState, BillingCountry, BillingPostalCode, 
       BillingLatitude, BillingLongitude
FROM Account
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you can safely remove compound fields from your export as they're read only and updatable only by its component fields.
Look for "Address" or "Geolocation" type fields, remove them from your select/query and voila.

For Account, in my case I removed ShippingAddress, BillingAddress and a custom geolocation field.